# Improve this custom function addClassIfVarDefined() or share better solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm developing an app in Node.js, and I'm new at it. So I wrote a function that adds `active` class to topNavigation's `li` if a user is in corresponding section, if not it doesn't. This function works but it's uncomfortable and wrong. I'm looking for better way to handle it. Please share better solution.

```
var addActive = function(requiredPage, currentPage) { // Current page defined only in certain pages

if( requiredPage == currentPage)
    return 'class="active"';
else
    return null;
};
```

In cerrtain pages (pages that wrote in topNavbar) I define a variable `appSection` in others I don't, because I don't want to define a class where it useless. So I make this

```
addActive('gallery', (typeof appSection === "undefined" ? '' : appSection))
```

Sorry if I made grammar errors. Learning english. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
var addActive = function(requiredPage, currentPage) {
    return requiredPage === currentPage ? 'class="active"' : '';
};
```

Use it like:

```
typeof appSection !== "undefined" && addActive('gallery', appSection);
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Unfortunotely I can't upvote your answer, because I need 15 reputation. But thank you. But I totally can't understand why does it work. Could you describe me what does it mean please: typeof appSection !== "undefined" && addActive('gallery', appSection);

Comment: Welcome and +1, anyways, the function will be called if the first condition is true, that's it. It's like `if(typeof appSection !== "undefined") addActive(...)`.